# Would an endothermic star be possible?

Tags: magic, physics

Real world stars are a mass of exothermic nuclear reactions.
But what if there were some sort of star-like astrological phenomenon that somehow underwent an endothermic reaction?

I would like to know if the existance of this 'endothermic star' could be justified. Scientific explanations are preferred, but I'm willing to stretch to magic means if there are no plausible scientific explanations.

**Further Clarification:**
Preferably something that has gravity/can be orbited, but ultimately anything that would have a cooling effect on other nearby celestial bodies.

---

Note: I'm not actively writing a story, this is purely hypothetical for the time being.

Comment: When you say star-like what do you mean? You take away the exothermic nuclear reactions and you don't really have anything that resembles a star.

Comment: magic and physics together?

Comment: @JoeKissling Preferably something that has gravity/can be orbited, but ultimately anything that would have a cooling effect on other nearby astral bodies.

Comment: @L.Dutch A physics-magic combination would be fine, though I'd prefer a higher amount of physics than magic.

Comment: Afaik physics goes with what we know about our world, magic goes against what we know...

Comment: @L.Dutch Yes, but it's possible to balance the two. Conjuring "an unknown magical metal made of magic" vs conjuring "a sheet of Grade 38 Titanium Alloy" or "fire from nowhere" vs "producing ignited hydrogen".

Comment: If even [The Doctor doesn't want a piece of this](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Cold_star), you have to ask yourself .. how far from the pack have you strayed? :)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition "Cold burning star? Do me a favour!" Half the reason I decided to ask this question.

Comment: @Pharap [Astral body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astral_body) is probably not the term you were after. Astronomical or celestial body, or simply [astronomical object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_object), is probably what you meant.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I think I mangled 'celestial body' by getting my Latin and my Greek mixed up. That or I was aiming for 'astronomical body' and my brain got lazy and contracted it.

Comment: This question might be better suited for Physics.SE, all it does here is show that WorldBuilding.SE has become a dumping ground for "I don't know where to ask" questions. The last line of the question (not writing a story) makes it poignant.

Comment: @dotancohen Aside from the fact I've stated I'll also accept answers that employ magic (i.e. I am willing to accept loose/handwavey explanations because I'm not asking about whether such a thing could exist in the real worl), the other reason for not asking on Physics.SE is because they tend to assume the person asking the question is well versed in physics or answer with a bunch of complicated equations or at the very least one that involves some form of maths (vectors, quotients, matrices, determinants etc) and I don't really care about the equations involved.

Comment: @L.Dutch I'm writing a story in which magic is very logical and can be explained with physics-like explanations. Magic and Physics can go together if you do it right.

Comment: Have you considered a Neutron Star on its way to becoming a Black Hole.  - https://theboard.byu.edu/questions/55367/ ... I don't know if that can help you refine your question or not.  "The r-process is endothermic, in that the energy required to overcome electromagnetic repulsion exceeds the energy released by combining heavy nuclei into heavier nuclei. During the core collapse initiating a supernova, there is enough excess energy to fuel this fusion. ... 1 of 2

Comment: 2 of 2 Because of the high nuclear binding energy of these new nuclei, we can derive energy by fissioning these heavier elements (such as certain radioactive uranium isotopes) in nuclear reactors. Essentially, the input energy needed to split these nuclei is less than the energy generated by breaking their nuclear bonds (an exothermic process), and thus we can reason that the process creating these nuclei (the r-process) must be endothermic."

Comment: Pharap, i think you should reduce the scope on your question. These tags are problematic together, as risks putting your question in "too broad' space. I'd suggest dropping the [tag:magic] tag.

Comment: I initially misread the last line as "I'm actually writing a story, this is purely hypothetical for the time being." - I was wondering what the plan for putting it into non-hypothetical use after the story was finished was!

Comment: If it shines, it's exothermic. If it doesn't shine, is it really a star?

Answer (score 42):

Technically those do exist, they are called [Type II Supernova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_II_supernova), though the endothermic part is very brief and then followed by a very exothermic reaction. The exothermic nuclear reaction is what make a star a star. Once the nuclear reaction starts taking more energy than it gives off, like when attempting to fuse iron in large stars, it collapses in on itself. Stars are held up by radiation pressure from the nuclear fusion, without it they cease to be stars.

Otherwise, A star is by its very nature an exothermic reaction.

**Edit**

Has mass but does not warm a object around it. You could orbit a black hole that does not have an [accretion disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accretion_disk). The cooling would come from space itself and for all practical purposes the black hole would give off very little heat.

Comment: On this note, if a black hole of equal mass was swapped for our star, the gravitational effects on our planet would remain unchanged. It would take eight and a half minutes for us to notice this. It has been theorized that there are solar systems made up of trapped rouge planets with black holes at their centers, however due to Hawking radiation, we can't see them since they take in more energy than they release. We have to see it to know it exists. That larger a black hold the longer it takes for it to disperse. One the size of our star would take twice the time our universe has existed.

Comment: Nice answer. See also [an answer on Physics Stack Exchange](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/215780/56299).

Comment: @Kayot Check your math. It would take way longer for a black hole the mass of our sun to evaporate than a mere 28,000,000,000 years. It'd be closer to 100,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 or 10^67 years.

Comment: @Shufflepants In a vacuum... but going through the Milky Way's corona it will pick up >> 10^25 hydrogen atoms per second, while it takes >> 10^10 years to emit one hydrogen atom's worth of mass via Hawking radiation, so 10^67 isn't enough. Although I guess it's moot since nucleons are supposed to have been long decayed by then.

Comment: @Charles Yes, of course in a vacuum. Also, unless otherwise specified, all animals are assumed to be perfectly spherical, identical, and frictionless. But even accounting for a lack hole taking on more mass in the near term, the figure is still approximately correct considering adding on 10^25 * 10^10 years = 10^35 years only affects the time by 10^(-30)%

Comment: Only if protons decay. The lower bound for their life is 10^43 years if I recall correctly. It's even worse than that, not only is there the interstellar medium but even absorbing the cosmic microwave background photons can outpace the loss to hawking radiation.

Comment: @JoeKissling But as you go forward in time, the temperature of the cosmic background radiation becomes more and more red shifted. In only ~700 billion years, the CMB will be so red-shifted it will be beyond our current thresholds for detection.

Comment: @Shufflepants Beyond our threshold for detection doesn't mean the black hole will not continue to gain mass for a very long time. According to [this](http://www.physics.hmc.edu/student_projects/astro62/hawking_radiation/cbr.html) the break even point, even with continued cooling, is 10^29 years.

Comment: @JoeKissling 10^29 years is still approximately 0% of 10^67 years.

Comment: @Shufflepants Good point. These timescales are ludicrously long.

Comment: @JoeKissling Semi-relevant [xkcd-what-if](https://what-if.xkcd.com/84/), showing how # of digits is rather important (moreso than real numbers)

Comment: @Delioth I agree completely. The time I listed was to point out that while we won't be able to detect it in 700 billion years, the influence of the CMB will last much longer than that.

Comment: Moving these comments back to your original post, I'm not sure I agree with your characterization of a Type II supernova. Presumably, you are referring to iron fusion as the endothermic part. This happens after the collapse from electron degeneracy to neutron degeneracy, as a result of the shockwave from that collapse. This is the same shockwave that blows the outer layers of the star off into the observed part of the supernova. So I don't think you can characterize this as an endothermic star at all, its just an endothermic reaction that occurs in the violence of a supernova.

Comment: @kingledion you are right, it is a shaky comparison. But before it was further clarified as to what the OP was asking it was the closest thing to an endothermic reaction in a star like object could have

Comment: "then followed by a very exothermic reaction" -In the context of a Type II SN, that made me giggle.

Answer (score 37):

There's a problem here: nothing is colder than deep space.

Since there is no interstellar medium, the only way heat transfers in space is by radiation. Any object facing deep space and not illuminated by a star or itself will, left on its own, gradually cool to a little over absolute zero, heated only by the cosmic microwave background radiation.

There's no way to "suck" heat out of something that's not being radiated in that direction. You could have planets orbiting a dead star that emits nothing, or possibly a planet that is a wanderer, and they would be extremely cold; any remaining atmosphere lying frozen as a blanket of snow.

Comment: This. You could spin it just another way: it is not possible to create an endothermic star (by your argument) because "endothermic" means "takes thermal energy from the environment" and "deep space" means "there is no environment to take thermal energy from" (if you ignore any unhappy photons whizzing around and being caught, which is hardly what one would figure as "endothermic").

Comment: Black holes are colder than background. If a planet orbits a black hole even the faint cosmic background radiation from that direction is sucked up. However this wouldn't produce much of a cooling effect under most circumstances, unless the black hole is very large and close. (super massive  to minimize tidal heating)

Comment: Yes, black holes truly emit no radiation from themselves. I was under the impression that most have a hot belt of input matter around them, although that may just be because ones that don't are impossible to see.

Comment: Yes, @DonaldHobson, technically being "behind" a black hole will shield you from some part of the background radiation. But... if you use "endothermic" like "exothermic", i.e., in significant sizes, I'm pretty sure the OP did not think of this minuscule amount of energy (the background is what, 2°K?).

Comment: Are you sure that [space is cold](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SpaceIsCold)? <Warning: Tv Tropes link>

Comment: @xDaizu that's why I was careful to say "facing deep space and not illuminated by a star or itself". The ISS has heat dissipation problems. Voyager 1 is apparently somewhere in the region of -100C due to carrying its own radiothermal generator.

Comment: @DonaldHobson: Black holes may be colder than space and thus absorb energy from it, but when you're close to a black hole, general relativity says that the CMB that reaches you from the non-black hole-covered area of space is blue-shifted, so the effects may cancel each other out; someone should do the math.

Comment: Space is not cold.  Space is vacuum.  Heat is movement of matter.  Matter can neither gain nor lose heat to a vacuum.

Comment: Technically one could argue almost anything is colder than deep space, as anything but deep space will facilitate heat transfer away from the object due to conduction. I see your point though.

Comment: Space is "cold" in the radiative sense of Stefan-Boltzmann law, since there's nothing to radiate anything. But it seems that the coldest element in the universe is pedantry.

Comment: @Xavon_Wrentaile Space is very cold, not a complete vacuum.  Matter is sparse in space, but it exists.

Comment: @WeckarE. Cold is not a measurable thing. It is a term used to compare heat levels. While Xavon_Wrentaile was wrong about space being a vacuum, his definition if heat is correct. By that definition, only things with lower density than deep space are colder. I'm sorry, I don't see how an object conducting heat (and it would be mostly radiant heat transfer, not conductive since there's not much mass in space to conduct heat) to deep space makes that object _colder_ than deep space.  The source of the heat transfer Is warmer than the recipient, as long as we're obeying thermodynamics..

Comment: @pjc50 True vacuum has no mass and therefore would be colder than deep space. Deep space is not quite absolute zero. Better to say that deep space is the coldest thing we know aside from absolute, perfect vacuum.  Your statement about sucking heat is badly worded.  Energy moves from high potential to low. An object of low potential seems to attract energy. That's why a window seems to radiate cold on a clear winter day. An endothermic body would be one that draws in more than it radiates, which we commonly think of as a black hole, though Hawking has shown us that they eventually evaporate.

Answer (score 14):

This is probably nutty, but something like adiabatic magnetic refrigeration might work. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_refrigeration

Imagine taking the iron core of a dead star. Apply a mind-bogglingly large external magnetic field, using something like solar-system-wide Helmholtz coils. Maybe Magneto could do it. Anyway, once the system equilibrates to the new high field, the iron core will be magnetized, meaning all of its magnetic domains are aligned along the field.

Now start to lower the externally applied magnetic field. I'm not sure how to estimate over what timescale it can be lowered, but there would be an incredible amount of energy stored in a stellar core sized chunk of iron, so I would guess centuries just comparing that mass to a standard adiabetic magnetization refrigerator mass.

As the magnetic field decreases, the core's magnetic domains will start to randomize by absorption of thermal energy. But until the magnetic field is zero, the domains will reorient themselves to this lower energy state, resulting in a "spontaneous" decrease in entropy, cooling the body.  So over whatever time scale you lower the magnetic field, the body would overall be colder than surrounding space, with the cooling power equal to the decrease in stored magnetic energy over time.

It would be artificial to set up, but in principle it could be a relic from an older hyper-advanced civilization, with the magnetic field machinery just now decaying when we find it.

Comment: Not much spare thermal energy floating out there in space, but I like the concept.

Comment: Initially the thermal energy comes from the core's internal state.  If you have perfectly aligned magnetic domains, then any temperature other than absolute zero has enough thermal energy to randomize some of them.

Comment: I like it, but won't gravity still make it burn?

Comment: @Polyergic If it really were a core of iron, it wouldn't burn. As far as we know, everything heaver than iron in the universe was made in supernovae, not stellar fusion.  Of course it might just collapse if you tried to make it too big.

Comment: @nijineko When you're talking about deep space, the random atoms of helium and hydrogen and whatever that exist between stars are functionally the same as thermal energy.  Though they would not drive this refrigerator.  Light would though.

Comment: @bloer Derp, of course.  It would just be very hot.

Answer (score 13):

Black holes are endothermic in a sense, although their swathe of destruction causes an exothermic signature.

I guess cold neutron stars could be endothermic, as  their neutrons evaporate. It's complex, because these mechanisms are quantum physical rather than chemical, but in the sense of absorbing heat rather than emitting light you have to go to the dark side - certainly endothermic stars couldn't emit black body radiation.

Comment: For practical purposes a solar mass black hole is cold. A neutron star is a good idea if you want to magic a way to cool it. Otherwise, you won't get a cold one for a very very long time.

Comment: Not actually true. Black holes emit [Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation), and actually lose mass over time when matter is not falling in. In the long run, they will lose more energy than they gain. That said, the long run is very long indeed and they can act as endothermic bodies for a very long time if there is sufficient material to feed them.

Answer (score 8):

For the purposes of writing a science fiction story, these answers are not necessarily satisfactory. The concept of an endothermic star might appear in the mind to be an icy blue sphere of radiating energies unknown to modern physics. In reality, the concept is quite different.

For something to be endothermic, it must absorb energy from its surroundings, but this is not seen in space typically. In space, where the radiant temperature is a few Kelvin, there are limited sources of energy for such a star to feed off of. That is, they are limited but not nonexistent.

Recently, the discovery of gravitational waves has made ripples (sorry) in the scientific community. It is conceivable, with a bit of a stretch, that an endothermic star could be at a nexus point between multiple binary star systems, where each creates gravitational waves that pass over the endothermic star, and the waves enter a superposition of energy at this point.

The energy in the space of the star could be used to help heavier elements undergo nuclear fusion (remember that the fusion of elements heavier than iron requires more energy than it could release, making the process endothermic). This star would still release some light, and thus it would work perfectly in a science fiction novel. Attached is an image of what the system would look like, with the scale of distance being in hundreds of light years.[image: The blue gravitational waves meet at the central point of the endothermic star where their energy could somehow be used to fuse heavy elements]

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! Interesting answer. If you have the time please [take the tour](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and [visit the help center](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: To be macroscopic those would have to be some incredibly energetic gravity waves.  Like, take a few hundred extremely massive black holes (each maybe the mass of the Laniakea Supercluster), arranged in small groups with stable orbits at nontrivial fractions of $c$, and the groups in a dyson-swarm-like arrangement around the nexus.  (And I thought the empire's Maw was hard to navigate!)  Somehow, that level of ridiculous makes me like the idea more.  (Experiment to prevent heat-death fails because nexus cancels out... something...)

Answer (score 3):

In the Electric Universe Theory/Hoax stars are "sumps" that soak up all the cosmic electricity around them. I think the idea is that a star's electromagnetic field is the source of gravity, and the star "burns" because the flow of ions is concentrated there. The electricity comes from outside the star, and the visible star is just an artifact of this electrical phenomena.

I've read a few articles that discuss this concept, or rather, I tried. The logic is often circular, and the whole concept is probably magic dressed up as pseudo-science. [Here](http://www.i-sis.org.uk/How_the_Plasma_Universe_Creates_Galaxies_and_Stars.php) (or [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170331075502/http://www.i-sis.org.uk/How_the_Plasma_Universe_Creates_Galaxies_and_Stars.php)) is a heady article with I think explains the concept in detail.

Comment: Your link appears to be dead.

Comment: @kingledion Seems to be working fine for me, but I added an extra copy to the Internet Archive no less.

Answer (score 3):

Would a [black dwarf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_dwarf) be endothermic?  Black dwarf stars are a theoretical type of star that has not yet had sufficient time to form in the universe.  It is hypothesised that our own Sun may end its days as a black dwarf a quadrillion years from now.

Comment: Black dwarves would not be endothermic.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! If you have the time please [take the tour](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and [visit the help center](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about the site. According to the link you provided a black dwarf would not be endothermic, just not very hot. But I think this is a good answer as black dwarfs haven't been mentioned as of yet and are a nice addition. Could you think of a sci-fi way of making a black dwarf appear to be endothermic? +1 from me anyways

Comment: @Secespitus How is it a good answer if it is wrong? I don't mean to discourage the OP either but answers are good only if they are true. If this was just a doubt, it would be better suited as a comment. Or even better, the OP could have done more research and found it out.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code The question includes "magic" as a tag. Therefore I don't think it's necessary to be "correct" in this question. That's why I asked the answerer for an idea about how to make this work by using a black dwarf as a starting point and adding sci-fi ideas.

Comment: @Secespitus Ok then

Answer (score 3):

There is a very general problem with your request: **A true and permanent radiation sink violates the second law of thermodynamics** (you take entropy away from the universe). This law is among the most universal laws in physics; it governs black bodies and black holes, indeed it probably governs the universe as an entity as well.<sup>1</sup>

Now that law only applies to closed systems. Maybe what you are looking for is a processor cooler at a stellar scale? That is, a mechanism to guide the heat away from the star and emit it "somewhere else". If you don't want to have an orbiting heat pipe<sup>2</sup> (it's orbiting so that it's always behind the cold star and does not spoil the view) I'd suggest a mechanism like magical micro mirrors (the marketing term was m<sup>3</sup>) that reflect incoming radiation at an angle perpendicular to all three spatial dimensions. Poof, gone. Make sure it is a one-way mirror though (you know, the second law).

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> See, for example, the [Wikipedia article on the holographic principle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holographic_principle)</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Siphoning (nice word) the energy "away" would, in turn, use more energy, just like your fridge or your CPU cooler. The colder you want the object, the more energy you need to stem the natural flow of entropy. On a stellar scale you probably need a stellar energy source (something like a death star 2.0 turned beer cooler). That energy source / working star would better be far away because actually you seem to want it cool, locally. So you would need a massive energy conduit from a working star to your (very) dark star, and then the heat pipe going "away".</sub>

Comment: My thoughts exactly. It could appear to be endothermic as long as *something* is siphoning off the energy to a different location.

Comment: At first I thought you were being a bit overbearing with entropy.  But for a body to continually absorb energy, it would have to remain 'colder' than everything around it, even as it absorbed energy.  That energy has to go someplace, or it warms the body.

Comment: In a more prosaic context, this is exactly why you cannot have a single-unit cooler (i.e. the reverse of a heater). The best you can have is a heat-pump with a cold end and a hot end, which is why A.C. units have two parts.

Comment: @OscarBravo I was thinking about this -- I think you still need a hot end even for your heater ... that is, heating something beyond equilibrium temperature is decreasing local entropy (I think) and needs a process (e.g. generator, electric energy transfer) which increases temperature elsewhere, in addition to the actual heat generated where you want it. You increase entropy elsewhere more than you decrease it locally. That is less obvious when you just burn something because the chemical energy was created by processes long ago, with sunlight, so the system to consider is huge.

Comment: @OscarBravo Actually, another thought: You can have a single-unit cooler, i.e. "create cold" without heat elsewhere at the same time: Certain chemicals, like salts dissolving in water, become cool. This uses chemical energy stored in the separated compounds, much like a candle. The excess entropy is temporally and spatially separated from the use.

Answer (score 2):

A normal star emits "warm radiation" which adds energy to anything that absorbs the radiation. What you seem to want is a source of "cold radiation" which subtracts energy from anything that absorbs it.

Something like this doesn't exist in physics. Well, there is [laser cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_cooling), but that only works on individual atoms under lab conditions.

So you would need to make up some form of fictional electromagnetic anti-radiation which is emitted by some kind of equally fictional exotic matter which the star consists of.

Answer (score 0):

I think if the author were to have his characters declare that the body cannot be truly endothermic due to the second law, it would be a great starting point to having them look for where the energy is going.  Finding out where could be a great quest for an entire series.

You could pick various of the answers here and use a separate story to explore what that answer predicts would be the 'trick' that would allow the phenomenon to appear as a perfect endothermic body.  Then have your heroes prove that that trick doesn't exist.

And you could pick your favorite and have them find the secret in the last episode.  Irony would have it turn out to be something of a hoax (Miniature storage cells with massive capacity being charged up to power the RV of a cute EBE family.)

Comment: While this is a worthwhile path that a story could take, if one wants to focus on the endothermic star, I don't think it is actually an answer to the question as asked, and have flagged it for review.

Comment: Xalorous you make an interesting point/scenario but as the others mentioned it doesn't really address the question being asked.  This would be a good note at the bottom of an answer addressing the question that was asked.